# Delete single row in sqlite DB with react and express

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, express

As the title said, im trying to delete a single user with a click on the button in the Table. But it deletes all users. So i think i have to map the single id´s to the button. But how?
This is my first CRUD App, so im not that experienced yet.

here is my React userTable component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

const API_ENDPOINT = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT

class Userstable extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      isLoading: false,
      isError: false
    }
  }


async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isLoading: true })
    const response = await fetch(`${API_ENDPOINT}/api/users`)
    if (response.ok) {
      const users = await response.json()
      this.setState({ users, isLoading: false })
    } else {
      this.setState({ isError: true, isLoading: false })
    }
  }

render() {
    const { users, isLoading, isError } = this.state

    if (isLoading) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }

    if (isError) {
      return <div>Error</div>
    }

    return users.length > 0
      ? (
        <table className="table" id="tblData"  >
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style={{ borderTopLeftRadius: "4px" }}>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>email</th>
              <th style={{ borderTopRightRadius: "4px" }}></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {this.renderTableRows()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      ) : (
        <div>
          No users.
      </div>
      )
  }

renderTableHeader = () => {
    return Object.keys(this.state.users[0]).map(attr => 
    <th key={attr} >
    {attr}
    </th>)
  }

deleteTableRow = () => {
  return this.state.users.map(user => {
    return (
      fetch(`${API_ENDPOINT}/api/users/${user.id}`, {method: 'DELETE'})
    )
})
}

renderTableRows = () => {
    return this.state.users.map(user => {
      return (
        <tr key={user.id}>
          <td>{user.id}</td>
          <td>{user.regname}</td>
          <td>{user.regemail}</td>
          <td className="delButton" onClick={this.deleteTableRow}>&#10005;</td>
        </tr>
      )
    })
  }
}
export default Userstable
```

and here is my express Backend route:

```
router.delete("/users/:id", (req, res, next) => {
  var sql = "DELETE FROM Users WHERE id = ?"
  var params = [req.params.id]
  db.run (sql, params, (err) => {
          if (err) {
              res.status(400).json({ "error": res.message })
              return;
          }
          res.status(200)
          res.json({ "answer": "success" })
          return
      });
});
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the id in `onClick`:

```
<td className="delButton" onClick={() => this.deleteTableRow(user.id)}>&#10005;</td>
```

and send the request with the id:

```
deleteTableRow = (id) => {
   fetch(`${API_ENDPOINT}/api/users/${id}`, {method: 'DELETE'})
}
```

Comment: i already tried this, but this gives me the error: "Warning: Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type." and my insertion got instantly deletet without a click on the button

Comment: ah, my mistake! didn´t use an arrow function. But this also deletes all my data, and not the single row

Comment: I think it has to do with mapping through the state. You can just send the request without the map function